# Want a specific image for fb liking an article on site..different images when posting articles on fb

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a like button that works and that takes the image I have specified through the following parameter and attaches to a user liking the post on there feed.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.org/images/logo_50x50.gif" />
```

I basically want to use this image only for my users when they like an article, but when posting from a specific article "on my facebook site"..I want to be able to still select the images pulled up from that link. That doesn't happen. All I get right now is what I specified in my og:image parameter.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you just told Facebook which image to use - it's supported to have multiple og:image tags but i'm not sure if which image to display is deterministic, random, or uses a picker like the system used when you don't specify an image